# How to I remove Featured Image from the Posts/Category Lists?

Tags: post-thumbnails

It seems like this should be easy, but I do not see an option to exclude the featured image from the category index pages, or posts index pages (whatever they are called).  Here is an example of the page I'm referring to: `https://wp.oldmagazinearticles.com/titanic_history/`
You see, there are multiple featured images, one for each article, however we just want to list of articles, no featured images.

I've looked through all the settings on WordPress and the Asta there, which we are using, and did an internet search.  I find articles to remove feature image from the individual posts, but not the post list pages.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Archives don't normally show featured images, so this is specific to your theme, and thereby out of scope here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Astra Theme , you need to create a new "archives" template and set the display conditions. In that template, you can choose only to show what you want and hide or remove the images.

This is Theme related, and not WordPress related as @vancoder pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @vancoder too.  I'll take it from here.